# Bash Script - Get song artist from command line

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a bash command/program that can get information about a song from the command line? I want to get things like album, artist, length, etc.

Format is .mp3

Comment: Are you talking about any particular file format?

Comment: ...or particular data source?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try `exiftool`, it's very easy to use:

```
$ exiftool -Title -Artist -Album -Duration  ScarboroughFair.mp3
Title                           : Scarborough Fair
Artist                          : 莎拉 布莱曼
Album                           : 月光女神
Duration                        : 0:04:11 (approx)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know `exiftool` did it's magic for other things than pictures, too.

Comment: Not only CAN you do it, this is the best way given that `id3tool` only has setters.

Answer (score 1):

Try id3v2 for example, or id3tool, or simply id3

Comment: strangely `id3tool` and `id3v2` don't seem to have a getter, just a setter

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try the -f command. It will allow you to search for a file name (therefore the song name).

Comment: I deeply wonder what `ls` (whose out you should never parse, anyway!) has to do with the users question.